# How do I find Windows Server Domain Name workstation belongs to by IP address in local network?

Tags: windows, networking, domain

Company workstations belong to several domains and I have to find out exact Workstation domain  by workstation IP. Is it possible from command line or do I have to call an administrator ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do something with reverse DNS. For a start, type in:

```
ping -a ip.address.here
```

at a Windows command line and, if you're lucky, you'll get a response like the following:

> Pinging Laptop-Name.Domain.Com [ip.address.here] with 32 bytes of data:

But, then again, you may not! Try it with a PC on a different domain to really see.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `nslookup IP.Address.here` to see which computer is behind the ip address. (see [nslookup command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200525))

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct correlation between a hosts ip address and it's domain membership. As the other answers suggest, you could perform a reverse lookup on the ip address to see what FQDN is returned and determine from the DNS suffix what AD domain the workstation might be joined to, but there are several caveats:

This assumes that a reverse lookup zone is configured and that PTR records are registered in the zone for the workstations.

This assumes that the workstations are not receiving DHCP option 15 (DNS domain name) from a DHCP server if the workstations are configured to get their ip address/configuration from a DHCP server.

For example, there's no discernable difference in a PTR record for a domain joined workstation and a non-domain joined workstation if the workstations receive their ip address/configuration from DHCP and DHCP option 15 is used and is configured with a DNS suffix that matches the AD domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Domain"
```